Inequality involving fractional moments of distributions
Suppose we have two bounded non-negative random-variables $X,Y$. Suppose that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=1$ and their other moments obey $\mathbb{E}[X^m] \geq \mathbb{E}[Y^m]$ for all integer $m \geq 2 $.
Does it follow the inequality is also true for all   real $m \geq 1$, i.e. their fractional moments?
More generally the question comes from studies of information and entropy in physics. Occasionally we encounter a Shannon-entropy like object $\mathbb{E}[X \log X]$. However, this may be hard to average directly, and we can instead try to compute $\mathbb{E}[X^m]$ since $\frac{d}{dm} \mathbb{E}[X^m]|_{m=1} = \mathbb{E}[X \log X]$. In many cases, the integer $m$ case can typically be done straightforwardly. Then oftentimes a non-rigorous guess is performed to interpolate from the integers to the reals (this analytic continuation is called the 'replica trick'). My question is really whether in some cases, information about the integers suffices to constrain the behavior of the entire function, in particular, whether the there is an inequality on the information of two random variables of the form  $\mathbb{E}[X \log X] \geq \mathbb{E}[Y \log Y]$ etc.

Where does this question come from?

I added some motivation. It seems like  many people don't like just the bare-bones formulation of the question (I thought it was very clean and appealing) and have voted to close the question, in which case ¯\ (ツ)/¯. But the basic question underpins a bigger and more commonly encountered situation in information theory/statistical physics etc.

You can use Hölder's to get $E|X^{n+r}| \le (E|X^n|)^{1-r} (E|X^{n+1}|)^{r}$, if that's useful.

Why did this get closed?

@usul great question. I had no idea this question is so polarizing: liked by so many people (the upvores), yet also disliked by so many others(the closure)...

No, an inequality of integer moments does not imply the same inequality for all real moments above 1.
Consider the following distributions:
$X=0$ w.p. $0.598$, $2$ w.p. $0.4$, $100$ w.p. $0.002$.
$Y=0$ w.p. $20.6/21.6$, $21.6$ w.p. $1/21.6$.
For moments 1 and 2, X and Y have the same value: 1 and 21.6, respectively. For moments strictly between 1 and 2, Y has a larger moment, and for moments above 2, X has a larger moment.
I verified this by graphing the functions
$$0.4 * 2^x + 0.002 * 100^x$$
$$21.6^x/21.6$$
and observing where they crossed.

Thank you. OK, so the inequality as stated does not hold, but a much harder question would be what conditions can we impose on the growth of the integer moments so that the fractional moment inequality does hold? The reason why this may be possible is because for bounded random variables, the integer moments uniquely determine the distribution... maybe this is too difficult..
